# Mocking dependencies of a module singleton in unit testing (Python)

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, singleton, python-module

In a simple unit testing scenario, suppose I have the following module:

```
class DatabaseMediator:
    def __init__(self, mock_connection):
        self.db_connection = mock_connection if mock_connection is not None else connect()


databaseMediator = DatabaseMediator()
```

assuming `connect` is a method that might be imported from another module and establishes a db connection.

Now because we're unit testing, it is desirable to be able to test the class isolated way and therefore instantiate it without an actual database connection, so one could to this:

```
from database_mediator import DatabaseMediator

mock_mediator = DatabaseMediator(mock())
```

in order to get a testable instance of `DatabaseMediator` that doesn't actually have a database connection. However, as we know, when you import anything from a module in Python, the whole module is executed and therefore, the `databaseMediator` instance will also be created. This can become a problem however, e. g. when we're in a CI pipeline and there is no database instance to connect to and therefore this method throws an error.

Is there any way to have the dependencies of the singleton mocked? Or an overall better approach to the problem?

Comment: Not related, but i think  self.db_connection = mock_connection or connect() look more clean.

Comment: @funnydman thanks for the tip, I considered this, and I decided against it as it results in unwanted behavior when you pass `0`, for example.